# Passing one command from two into a variable

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have two commands I want to run on subprocess as `cmds = "ls;pwd"`, but I want to pass only the result of `ls` into variable `x`. How do I do this?

Comment: Run each command individually is an idea.

Comment: If all you want is the output from *ls* why are you invoking *pwd*? See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Run each command individually, and store/consume the result of the command which you need.